# Magento - tax rate based on selected currency

Tags: magento, currency, tax

Have a Magento site ver. 1.7.0.2

We have one store set up for, primary is UK, but also want to offer global sales (without multiple stores setup).

So we offer 3 selectable currencies on the site: UK - GBP (main), EU - Euro, US - USD

All prices are excluding vat/tax with a vat breakdown displayed at the cart and checkout.

For UK there is 20% VAT
For EU there is also 20% with a option to add valid EU vat number (which removes the VAT)

This all works fine.

However if you select the USD currency and add a item to the cart it gives a vat breakdown (20%), even though we dont want to add tax when USD is selected.

I should note that once you do checkout and have told the site you are in the US then is correctly removes the vat/tax.

So to clarify, we want it so that if the USD currency is selected on the site no tax/vat is added to the product price in the cart.

Is this possible?

Thanks
D

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting up multi-store configuration, using a store front for each location (UK/US/EU)

This will allow you to set the default country for each sub-store and then you can make the USA the default shipping destination / country for the US store, this will immediately apply the tax rules for this country when purchasing items from the US Store Front.

You said there's no multi-store, setup, but do you have a good reason why you don't want to use this kind of setup? it will allow you to do what you need.

The issue with your setup is that there's no way for the store to know where the customer is before they either login or select during the checkout, this is because you will only have one default location for all currencies.

There may well be a way of doing it like this, but not that I know of. This is what the store front and/or multistore is meant for and good at.

Comment: Hi Andrew - thanks, but yes multi store is not an option (for various reasons). Its actually working 'ok' at the moment if I could hide the VAT/TAX breakdown from appearing on the cart. when the customer goes to checkout (after cart) is shows correctly (because by then they have entered their location). So I guess if anyone knows how to remove/hide the tax breakdown from the cart that would do the job.

Comment: If you're wanting something simple you could just hide the tax block on that pahe with a simple CSS rule. there's a class for the cart page and tax block so you could easily {display: none} that